# WordPress Error 500 while installing Scalia theme

Tags: php, wordpress, web, themes

i am getting error 500 while importing scalia theme in my wordpress.

[image]

Comment: Internal server errors (error 500) are often caused by plugin or theme function conflicts, so if you have access to your admin panel, try deactivating all plugins.

Comment: check your apache error_log for more detail.

Comment: how to see apache error_log please tell steps in detail, i am not a coder. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file upload size is less. You can increase the file upload size. Two approach either set them in your script like so

```
<?php
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '<YOUR_VALUE_HERE>M');
```

If that does not work which rarely happens try creating your own `.htaccess` file with a text editor and input the following

```
php_value post_max_size <YOUR_VALUE_HERE>M
php_value upload_max_filesize <YOUR_VALUE_HERE>M
```

Hope this fix it!

Comment: post max size is 128   , upload max file size is 64

Comment: does both need to be same

Comment: `post_max_size : upload_max_size` = `2 : 1` i.e if upload max size is `100M` then post max size is `200M`

Comment: can you give me a screen shot how to edit it on cpanel, i am using go daddy

Comment: Hey I noticed that you changed the screenshot. This error come, when the file permission is not proper to all the files. Change the files permission to 755. You know how to do it or let me explain?

Answer (score 0):

in your wp-config.php file

1)Increasing the PHP Memory Limit

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

2)increase upload file size with value of your file

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '20M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '13M');
```

3. check .htaceess and files permissions if you have .htaccess rename it with for example .htaccess-old and create new one
4. use default theme then try to reinstall scalia